# Simulating a browser HTTP request method using CURL API in PHP

Tags: php, curl

This is very basic, but I am kind of confused where I am going wrong (learning how to implement a RESTful Web Service). The context is, I have a simple simulator.php file that simulates an HTTP request to one of my local PHP files. The local PHP file (index.php) does nothing but return a variable with a value. So it's pretty much like this:

```
<?php
$variable = 'hello';
return $variable;
?>
```

and my simulator.php file has the following:

```
?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/kixeye/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($contents);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

However, var_dump($contents) does not quite spit out the value of $variable which is being returned from index.php. I don't quite understand why not.

Comment: a blank string, actually if I simply echoed it, it works...so it was a really dumb question. By returning that variable, it wasn't being returned into the body of the Response method, it was simply a server side code that executed itself, and did not print anything out

Comment: Doesn't make sense that if you use `echo` instead of `var_dump` that it should work.

Comment: You want to use `echo $variable;` using `return` is only for functions

Answer (score 3):

`return`ing something outside of a function won't actually do anything. The cURL request you are making will return the HTML response from the requested page, so what your really want to do is `echo` the response rather than using `return`.

Just change the `index.php` script to this:

```
<?php
$variable = 'hello';
echo $variable;
?>
```

And your `var_dump()` in the second script will output `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$contents` variable will contain the web page being returned by the http request done with Curl. If you only need one value from `index.php`, just echo it, and its value will end up in `$contents` as a string.

If you want to retrieve several variables, you could try json encode them and then echo the result in `index.php`. Then you would have to do the reverse in your second script by json decoding `$contents`.

Alternatively, you could generate and echo valid php code in the first script, and then eval it in the second, but this is very bad practice (the use of `eval` is strongly discouraged).

See:

- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)